# Security issues with putting member id in URI segments?

Tags: channel-entries, entry, security

I'm using Safecracker Registration so that I can leverage Channels for my member data. I want to create pages that display member data in the frontend. Is there a security issue with using member ids (or even Channel entry ids) in the URIs? For example, http://domain.com/foo/123/ -- the 123 is the member id or entry id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, none whatsoever, those id's are simply unique identifiers, but are not meant to be private.